# powershell - get only audit failure event logs

Tags: powershell, hashtable, event-log

How to correctly use keywords property to get only audit failure event logs? i believe that keyword of failure log is -9218868437227405312 and trying to do

```
$filter=@{
    logname='security'
    providername='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
    keywords=-9218868437227405312
}
get-winevent -filterhashtable $filter
```

but i get not desired result, including success events.

or is there another way of getting audit failure logs using get-winevent?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Get-EventLog` instead of `Get-WinEvent`. It was roughly 10 times faster when I compared the two.

```
Get-EventLog Security -EntryType FailureAudit
```